# sanity of a plastic glass!

Tags: american-english

I recently microwaved a plastic glass to get rid of micro-organisms on it. I accidentally dropped the glass after taking it out. I said "Damn it! This glass is not sane anymore!"

Am I right in saying that?

Usually the word sanitary is used in contexts like that. But, is it still right if I use the word sane? Does American English allow me to use the word "sane" it that sentence?

Comment: Voting to close. Google "define:sane".

Comment: No it is not. Sane is referring to sanity and not to hygiene. You could say it is no longer hygienic. On another note I do question the sanity of microwaving plastic glasses, if there is any moisture on the glass, the heat would likely melt the container in a microwave

Comment: Why close? Sanity issues or sanitary problems?

Comment: I'd say the plastic glass was no longer *germ free*. I can't imagine myself in a situation saying a contaminated object is "not sane". Come to think of it, *contaminated* is the word you should have used.

Comment: Please post as answer, @Mari-LouA

Comment: @mplungjan ok :)

Comment: @Kris I really, really want to downvote you for that unforgivable piece of wordplay. In fact, I'm going to go and find every answer and question you've written, and downvote them all, just to teach you not to write a comment like that again. So ... I guess I have sanity problems.

Comment: Clearly the weight of argument is against you riship89. But don't concern yourself too much about the 'sanity' of tableware.  A doctor I know says that the trouble with people's (especially kids) health these days is that they don't ingest enough filth! No plastic mug or plate in our house is ever completely 'sane', in keeping with the humans who use them.

Comment: The Spanish word *sano* translates both to *sane* and *healthy* or *clean* in English... perhaps you just need to swear in Spanish instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the plastic glass was no longer *germ free*. I can't imagine myself in a situation saying a contaminated object is "not sane". Come to think of it, ***contaminated***, is the word you should have used.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-second_rule

Comment: Okay, okay. I get it. :)

Comment: @riship89: This answer can no longer accept new posts, but - the usual word for "germ-free" would be "sterile"

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft sterile fits better with the OP's exclamation.

Answer (score 1):

The Latin root *sanus* has both the meanings: *healthy, sane*.

However, *sanitized* has been adopted to refer to *free from germs* (hence healthy), while *sane* remains confined to a *mentally healthy* sense only.

English being so today, you cannot help but say 'it is not **sanitized** anymore,' though you could argue that *sane* is valid considering its roots:

> sane (adj.) Used earlier, of the body, with the sense of "healthy" (1620s)

Comment: No, you could not argue that. That would be in-sane