# Is "plastic glass" as a container a valid expression?

Tags: meaning, translation

In another question here ([sanity of a plastic glass!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137245/sanity-of-a-plastic-glass)) the term "plastic glass" is being used which sounds somewhat odd to me, but has not been brought into question by any respondents.

Maybe it is has to do with the fact that my mother tongue is German where a "Glass" is always made from glass, while a plastic cup would be be "Plastikbecher". (which would translate into plastic cup.)

Can anyone confirm this for me?

Comment: maybe this belongs in ELL, I just felt it fitted here due to the link to the other question. If the mods or community feels like it should go there, please also let me know.

Comment: It does sound weird to me, without context I would not understand what was meant (I would first think about something like plexiglas). "Plastic cup" is more commonly used for a container.

Comment: Have a look at the "sanity of a plastic glass" question for an example of context.

Comment: Up to this moment I would have agreed entirely with you and said that in Britain a glass is a glass and a plastic beaker is a plastic beaker. But we are currently staying in our daughter's house and I notice that she has some drinking receptacles made of plastic, that are on stems, a bit like the ones they give you on airlines for wine. I am not sure what I would call them other than 'plastic glasses'.

Comment: Ha! I was thinking the exact same thing. An oxymoron expression you might call it. I think what the OP is asking whether we can define a glass object as being plastic. In this case, it is the vessel, for want of an alternative word, that is made of plastic. But whoever says *a plastic drinking vessel*?

Comment: @NamSandStorm I understood it from the context, of course, but separately I wouldn't. The containers are plastic cups for me, as in your native language.

Comment: You can have _steel wool_

Comment: The problem is that plastic can be used to make mugs, beakers and other types of *cup*, (which were originally made of wood, metal, earthenware or whatever), but also to make tumblers, flutes, and other types of *glass* (which were, when named, only made out of glass). ? *A plastic* is too vague to catch on, IMHO.

Comment: Interestingly I have asked for a "glass glass" in a pub I went to because I realized the "glasses" they were using were plastic. The bartender understood what I wanted.

Comment: glass (glæs, glɑs) *n*. **4**. a tumbler or other comparatively tall, handleless drinking container. (Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc.), (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/glass) ; Others say "*usually* made of glass" not "necessarily made of glass".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only a slight addition to what's been said before, but I think it adds something.

A *plastic glass* (in the UK) would normally be used to refer to a plastic substitute for a drinking vessel usually made of glass (e.g. for picnics/camping or at concerts), and would normally be transparent (though as with glass glasses, many styles exist, translucent coloured wine "glass"es being quite common in camping shops).

A *plastic cup* may be provided for water, terrible coffee, etc. and is often white, though sometimes (for water) is transparent.  IME this is always a disposable cup.  A camping coffee cup made of plastic would be a *plastic mug* (and shaped like a normal mug), while a vessel for soft drinks might (in the UK, but not the US) be a *beaker* (the qualifier *plastic* isn't really needed there), with childish implications.

Finally for another meaning of glasses, "plastic glasses" can be used to refer to spectacles with plastic *lenses*, or with plastic *frames*.

Comment: I've never heard the word 'beaker' outside of a chemistry lab or The Muppet Show.

Comment: Is 'beaker' in this context a UK thing?

Comment: I'd never thought about it but apparently ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaker_%28drinkware%29)) it is a UK term.

Comment: +1 Everything but 'beaker' applies perfectly to the USA. Perhaps for clarification, "a glass" or "the glass" usually refers to a drinking glass (cup) or 'tumbler' (a word I've never used but sometimes it says it on the packaging).

Comment: @BrianDHall, Thanks, I've updated to reflect UK-specific usage.  perhaps any contributors from the rest of the commonwealth might like to chip in.  Tumbler is fairly common in the UK at least for a rather squat glass.

Comment: Just to add another difference - a `plastic cup` is usually considered flimsy and easily compressible to make it easily disposable.  The vessel being clear in that case would not make it a `plastic glass` since they usually mimic the properties (thickness and rigidity) of a vessel made of glass.

Comment: @JamesSnell, good point in the general case, except in the rock concert example above, the plastic pint "glasses"  (not "cups" IME) would be flimsy, compressible and disposable.

Comment: @ChrisH In India, its normal to call a steel (or plastic or ceramic or paper for that matter) tumbler a glass.

Comment: Thanks @aitchnyu, is this true only when a cold drink is served in it, or hot as well?  On my one too-short visit to India I only had tea in disposable (paper) containers - I would have used the word "cup", but don't recall what anyone else said.

Answer (score 22):

Sure.  Why not?  A chamois cloth needn't be made of chamois leather.  A wood golf club needn't be made of wood.  In Britain, a copper (2p or 5p coin) isn't made of copper. And my glasses have plastic lenses.

If you want to be pedantic about it, you can call it a clear, plastic beaker.  But in that case, make sure the polymer the beaker is made from is a thermoplastic polymer, rather than a thermoset...

Comment: +1. Certainly whenever I go to a concert, drinks are served in plastic glasses.

Comment: Sounds like my kind of concert :)

Comment: Personally I would not dignify any old 'wash leather' with the name 'chamois'.

Comment: This is a beaker: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/Beakers.jpg/607px-Beakers.jpg

Comment: I feel that in spoken language it would be acceptable to use "plastic glass", but why don't we say "paper glass" then? Also, does it have to be transparent and resemble a typical glass (wine glass, whiskey tumbler etc.) to be called a a plastic glass? What about these thick plastic cups we give to our kids?

Comment: @mplungian What would you call it if it was shaped like a wine-glass?

Comment: @NamSandStorm I think the transparency is important. Translucency is a borderline case.

Comment: @WS2 If my memory is correct, you can get cloths suitable for wiping windows in packets labelled "synthetic chamois leathers". But they are usually just referred to as "shammies".

Comment: @Pitarou I am enjoying this. Maybe I chose the wrong word, since translucency, transparency and even opacity are all properties of various types of glass. Glass containers in the context of "wine glasses" are available in designs incorporating these properties. What I meant to say is that a plastic glass would have to mimic the design and optical properties of an ordinary glass of the same function. To add fuel to the fire, modern camping "glassware" includes containers shaped like wine glasses but made from stainless steel.

Comment: It was an open secret that the company had used a paid volunteer to test the plastic glasses. Although they were made using liquid gas technology and were an original copy that looked almost exactly like a more expensive brand, the volunteer thought that they were pretty ugly and that it would be simply impossible for the general public to accept them. On hearing this feedback, the company board was clearly confused and there was a deafening silence. This was a minor crisis and the only choice was to drop the product line.  (Much Ado About English. Nicholas Brealey Publishing, 2006)

Comment: "A chamois cloth needn't be made of chamois leather" At the origin, it was!

Answer (score 6):

Whilst there are already correct answers I thought I would add some further illustration:

A Google search for "[plastic glasses](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22plastic%20glasses%22&oq=%22plastic%20glasses%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.5763j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)" (with the quote marks) returns almost a million results.  Of the top results returned, a large selection are from retailers selling "plastic glasses".

Your question title asks if the term is valid for a container.  The answer is absolutely yes.

In British English it is very common; I will defer to an American friend to clarify its usage in the States.

[Here](http://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/news/greater-manchester-news/manchester-derby-pubs-told-to-use-687348), in the Manchester Evening News, the term plastic glasses is used as you would expect.

> Police are advising pubs and clubs to use plastic glasses and employ extra door staff for Monday night’s crunch Manchester derby.

The term has also been used [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-highlands-islands-23848619) by the BBC:

> A proposal to extend the use of plastic drinks glasses to all pubs in the Highlands has been dropped.

As I mentioned in an earlier comment, the term plastic glasses is used regularly at concerts and sporting events.

You may well have asked for a **glass** of wine at the rock gig but you wouldn't be surprised if it was served in a plastic vessel of some description.

Comment: In summary, as long as the "alternative" plastic glass resembles the "original" glass in function and appearance, it is a valid and acceptable word?

Comment: Correct.  You will see from the tableware retailers that you can get wine glasses, tumblers, pint glasses, half pint glasses, shot glasses, etc. - all made of plastic.

Comment: The same goes for camping retailers and the stainless steel equivalents they sell, but are they an acceptable authority on the use of the English language?

Comment: I wouldn't say that they are an acceptable authority by a long stretch of the imagination but I was attempting to illustrate that the term "plastic glasses" is ubiquitous, certainly in the UK.

Comment: And for further information, I have never known a steel container be referred to as a "glass".  I think you'd be headed for "goblet" territory there!

Comment: you are so right. I double checked. Goblets for wine and tumblers for glasses. I hang my head in shame.

Comment: @ste On the other hand, you very often hear people refer to stainless steel utensils as "silverware", even though they're not made of silver.  In fact, you often hear people refer to plastic utensils as "silverware" also, and they're not even silver in color like steel is.

Answer (score 2):

From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/glass?s=t), see item #4.

> 1. a hard, brittle, noncrystalline, more or less transparent substance produced by fusion, usually consisting of mutually dissolved silica and silicates that also contain soda and lime, as in the ordinary variety used for windows and bottles.
> 2. any artificial or natural substance having similar properties and composition, as fused borax, obsidian, or the like.
> 3. something made of such a substance, as a windowpane.
> 4. a tumbler or other comparatively tall, handleless drinking container.
> 5. glasses, Also called eyeglasses. a device to compensate for defective vision or to protect the eyes from light, dust, and the like, consisting usually of two glass or plastic lenses set in a frame that includes a nosepiece for resting on the bridge of the nose and two sidepieces extending over or around the ears

It's worth noting that the merriam-webster.com & the oxforddictionaries.com sites reserve "glass" for a drinking vessel made from glass. But this has definitely become a popular (although lazy) saying for any type of relatively tall, handleless drinking vessel.

Comment: You might get downvotes for spelling Merrian-Webster and the Oxford Dictionary in lower-case letters. ELU are a very pedantic lot.

Comment: Only Oxford Dictionary—the other is a URL, and it would be incorrect to capitalise it. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Mari-LouA and Janus Bahs Jacquet. I revised me answer to be technically and stylistically correct. Unfortunately, I didn't reference a physical copy of the Oxford Dictionary.

Comment: Good answers here, but between the Oxford, Merrian-Webster and dictionary.com the authors seem to have different views on this.My 1992 edition of Webster's Dictionary and Thesaurus also is specific that the container should be made from glass. On the other hand it is 21 years old...

Comment: FWIW, it's Merria**m**